# try plus plural nouns?

Tags: vocabulary

> The fourth one he **tried** slid home without protest and turned as though it had been doing so for years. (The Silkworm, Robert Galbraith)

When I see the word, *tried*, I got this question: Can the word take plural nouns, e.g. ‘he tried four keys’; ‘she tried on four dresses,’ or take only singular nouns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, all of these are acceptable and ordinary:

> He tried three keys, none of which fit; but the fourth turned easily.
>   She tried on four dresses, but ended up buying a jumpsuit instead.

Comment: I'm grateful. And I get another one just comes up. Can 'door' itself be the complement of 'try'? (e.g. He tried _the door_ with the fourth key.)

Comment: @Listenever Yes it can; but when we speak of *trying a door* we usually mean attempting to open it without a key: *He tried the door to the library but found it was locked*.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve thought that the words that we don’t frequently use are difficult. But it seems that frequently used words themselves are the very words that are difficult, both in foreign language and mine. That gets me into learner’s dictionaries and [a twitter](https://twitter.com/EyeJoo/with_replies) account that are opened for learning Korean, [the count](https://twitter.com/urimal365) is run by a Korean national institute.

Comment: @Listenever Yes: it is the most frequently used words which have the largest range of meanings and uses; the rare ones are rare precisely because they have very narrow meanings which are not needed very often.